# How do you get your site on the YouTube Showcase?

Tags: youtube-api

My site is http://YouGamePlay.com.  I am using the YouTube API. I'm almost finished (happy) with the site and would like to know how to get it on the YouTube Showcase or to at least know the requirements to do so.

Thanks,
Mete Kamil

Answer (score 0):

I'm submitting your site on your behalf. I will get back with more details.

Comment: Did you hear anything back? Thanks.